# Casting a string to an Angular2 Form Validator type

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, validation, angular7

I'm using Angular 7 with Dynamic Forms

I store some form configs such as input: "text" etc to construct my forms. These are stored on a database. I store the validation as validator: "Validators.required". Now when I want to construct my dynamic forms and assign the validation to a form control using:

```
validations.forEach(valid => {
   validList.push(valid.validator);
});
return Validators.compose(validList);
```

I get the following error:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f14b5.png)

Now I'm assuming this is because I have Validators.required stored as a string which causes it to fail since it is not actually of type Validator which I've imported from angular/forms.

To my question: How can I convert the stored string to the Validators type. I've tried using `castValidator = (valid.validator as Validators);`
which gave me the same error.

I've thought about just doing a switch statement which checks the string then pushes the relevant Validators into the array, but that seems like a poor solution. I would have to account for every Validator type, not even thinking about custom validation.

Answer (score 0):

If data is saved in the form of string and data is in the form of key value pair. Then you will have to parse what you get from the database using JSON.parse().

Comment: Tried that, now I get the following error: `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token V in JSON at position 0` when using `validList.push(JSON.parse(valid.validator));`

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to extract data from something that does not exist. Try console.log(valid.validator);

Comment: It exists, using console.log gives - Validators.required, like I expected. The problem is that it is of type string, it needs to be of type Validators from the angular/forms library.

Comment: Can you please make a demo of what you are trying on stackblitz.